# ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hello In my oracle sql procedure , I am trying to get first sunday of selected year with code below

```
select next_day(to_date('01.01.'||v_year,'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'Sunday') into v_py  from dual;
```

`v_year` is number format like 2020 and `v_py` is date format
but this give me error like title.

When I wrote this query like below then I can see the result. Why isn't it working in procedure

```
select next_day(to_date('01.01.'||2020,'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'Sunday')   from dual;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you have in `v_year`?

Comment: I have 2020 @Mureinik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is valid. However, the second argument to `next_day()` is language-dependent, so I suspect that your database is not English.

You can check the language of the database with the following query:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter =  'NLS_LANGUAGE';
```

From there on, you can change the second parameter from `'Sunday'` to the corresponding day name in the database language.

It is also possible to build a language-indenendent expression, taking advantage of the fact that `to_char()` supports passing a language as last argument (unlike `nextday()`):

```
select trunc(to_date(v_year,'YYYY'), 'YYYY') 
    + 7 
    - to_char(trunc(to_date(v_year,'YYYY'), 'YYYY'), 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
into v_py  from dual;
```

`trunc(to_date(v_year,'YYYY'), 'YYYY')` is just another way to get the first day of the year from the given parameter.

Comment: Note `TRUNC(..., 'D')` depends on `NLS_TERRITORY`, result can be Monday, Sunday or Saturday (or even Friday for Bangladesh)

Answer (score 2):

Function `NEXT_DAY()` depends on `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, `TRUNC(..., 'D')` depends on `NLS_TERRITORY`, so either are not suitable for an NLS independent solution.

Use `TRUNC(..., 'IW')` which is based on ISO-8601 where begin of the week is always defined on Monday. Would be this:

```
v_py := TRUNC(TO_DATE('01.01.'||v_year, 'DD.MM.YYYY')+7, 'IW') - 1;
```

There is no need for `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM dual`